# Overwritting ndb.Model constructor

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have an nbd model defined as such:

```
class Attachment(ndb.Model):

    id              = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    mime_type       = ndb.StringProperty()
    contents        = ndb.StringProperty()
    modified_date   = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Attachment, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

As per documentation and coincidentally BDFL's direction, you can overwrite `__init__` in a ndb.Model subclass by calling the above `super()`; however, every time I'm trying to create a new instance as follows:
`Attachment(id='such',mime_type='img/jpeg')` keeps throwing errors that those args are unexpected.

What am I missing? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I should clarify that the model used to work perfectly fine before I started trying to overwrite the `__init__()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it appears that I messed up the model definition and was working due to divine providence. Relevant documentation:

> You cannot easily define a property named "key", "id", "parent", or "namespace". If you pass, for example, key="foo" in a constructor or populate() call, it sets the entity's key, not a property attribute named "key".

Comment: Yes id is reserved.. and you see it like `attachment.key.id()` and it's a numerical ID unless you have used a key_name

Comment: @GuidovanRossum I will, I'm not allowed to do so until 2 days from now.